# What is the best way for a class definition with PEP 526

Tags: python, pep

Lets say I have a class like below:

```
Class Foo:
    x: int
    y: List[int]
    z: int = 5

    def __init__(self, x:int, z: int = 5):
        self.x = x
        self.y = []
        self.z = z

   ### some other methods
```

My questions are;

1. If I am using the types inside the init function, isn't me using types at the class level become redundant?
2. I want the variable y to be initialized to an empty list for each instance. So, I didn't write the below code as it initialized the y at the class level. Is my understanding correct?

   ```
   Class Foo:
      x: int
      y: List[int] = []
      z: int = 5

      def __init__(self, x:int, z: int = 5):
          self.x = x
          self.z = z
   ```

I'm trying to improve my code quality, so if I am missing some primary understanding regarding it,  please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that difference between _instance attributes_ and _class attributes_. You shouldn't assign a value to `x`, `y`, or `z` inside the class namespace if you intend them to be instance attributes. All initialization should be inside `__init__`. If you do want them to be class attributes, you should annotate them with `typing.ClassVar`

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thank you. I think you answered the second question, saying my understanding is correct. Am I correct?

Also any input about the first question?